# login with phone number in django

Tags: python, django

I get this error when making changes

self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

## model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class Userperson(AbstractUser):

    gender_choice = [
        ('M', 'male'),
        ('F', "female")
    ]
    roles = [
        ('seller', 'Seller'),
        ('shopper', 'Shopper'), 
        ('serviceman', 'Serviceman')
    ]
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Fullname")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name="Phone",unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="userphoto/fullname", blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="userPhoto")
    phone_auth = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=gender_choice, blank=False, null=False, max_length=50)
    role = models.CharField(choices=roles, max_length=50)

    # ?
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone'
    #REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['fullname']
```

## admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Userperson

@admin.register(Userperson)
class personadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['fullname', 'phone', 'image', 'phone_auth']
```

What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: did you create a user manager?

Answer (score 0):

`Userperson` is a child class of `AbstractUser` and inherits all of methods and fields of parent class.

However `AbstractUser` has [`username`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e0442a628eb480eac6a7888aed5a86f83499e299/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L344) field and that is required.

You should set `username` inside `user_data` dictionary when creating new user object.

Also

> [USERNAME_FIELD](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD) - A string describing the name of the field on the user model that is used as the unique identifier

Are you sure that you want to identify user uniqueness by phone number? number with country code +987-1234-5678 and without it 0-1234-5678 (for country internal usage) will be two different users